# Testing coverage with PHPUnit and PDO

Tags: php, pdo, phpunit

As an exercise, I'm trying to reach 100% code coverage using PHPUnit, this is almost there, but it's the error bits which I've found difficult.

I have an example class which I has a similar issue to my real code, the exact code is not the issue, but the behaviour is the same.

```
class DBAccess  {
    private $db;

    public function __construct( \PDO $db ) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function select ()   {
        $data = false;
        if ( $stmt = $this->db->prepare("select * from user") ){
            if ( $stmt->execute() ){
                $data = $stmt->fetchAll();
            }
            else    {
                echo "Something went wrong";  // How to get here!
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

It's the one line which is stopping the 100% coverage.  The difficulty is that I need the prepare to pass, but the execute to fail.  I've managed this on updates by passing invalid foreign keys or fields to large for the table, but with a select, I'm not sure what can go wrong.

My test is...

```
class DBAccessTest extends TestCase {
    private $pdo;

    public function setUp() {
        $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=172.18.0.2;dbname=test",
                "test", "RkqwD1gjOdjkrwTt");
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function testSelect()    {
        $test = new DBAccess( $this->pdo );
        $this->assertTrue($test->select() != false );
    }
}
```

There are two possibilities I can think of

1. Assume that if the prepare has worked, that the execute will as well, but not particularly happy with that.
2. Somehow override the connection to make it fail in a controlled way.

Comment: Is that the exact function? Does it not take any parameters?

Comment: This is what mocks for. `\PDO` should be replaced with its mock. http://erichogue.ca/2013/02/best-practices/mocking-pdo-in-phpunit/

Comment: @ishegg It's not the exact function, as I mentioned it's a minimal example.  The essential part is that I cannot think of how to make a select fail once the prepare has worked.

Comment: @Axalix, thanks.  I've not done anything with mocking before, I will try and find more out about it.

Comment: No need to increase the visibility of `setUp()` from `protected` to `public`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly what [PHPUnit's test doubles](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.3/en/test-doubles.html) are for. And kudos for designing your classes in an object oriented way, so it's easy to inject mocks into them.

```
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class DBAccessTest extends TestCase
{
    public function test_something_goes_wrong()
    {
        // Create test doubles.
        $stmtMock = $this->createMock(\PDOStatement::class);
        $pdoMock = $this->createMock(\PDO::class);

        // Configure the stubs.
        $stmtMock->method('execute')
                ->willReturn(false);
        $pdoMock->method('prepare')
                ->willReturn($stmtMock);

        // Inject the mock.
        $test = new DBAccess($pdoMock);

        // Assert.
        $this->assertFalse($test->select());
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you really testing correct behavior here though? It seems like it’s only failing because you specifically told it to. So you’re really testing the implementation details. If just testing for the sake of code coverage why not use @codeCoverageIgnore? I’m legitimately asking by the way, I always had a conceptual problem with this kind of test

Comment: This is the sort of thing I was after, I will have a play with this in a few other places as well.  As for testing correct behaviour, surely how an application reacts to failures is just as important as when it functions normally.  If a system fails to react to problems in an orderly manner, then important actions could be lost, something slips between the cracks and figures stop adding up.  Telling the system to ignore code for coverage purposes is even worse IMHO.